# Running a Python script from VBA, not working

Tags: python, excel, vba

So, i`m trying to run a very very simple Python Script using VBA commands.

Tried many times the code below, the cmd opens but the script do not run at all.

Any ideas on the matter?

**Python Code**

```
# pip instal PyPDF2

import os

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


source_dir = os.getcwd()

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.startswith('Doc.'):
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=item, bookmark=None, pages=None)
           
    if item.endswith('pdf'):
        merger.append(item)
    

merger.write('try.pdf')
merger.close()
```

**VBA code to run the Python Script**

```
Sub running()

Dim obj As Object
Dim PythonExe As String
Dim Script As String

Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Program Files (x86)\python.exe"""

Script = "C:\Users\User\Documents\testesbulkpdf\firsttry.py"


obj.Run PythonExe & Script


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting it to execute python with a given path, so I changed the directory to get it to work.

I added in `/k` that should keep your prompt open and give errors. (honestly pretty unhelpful ones but its better than just flashing open and closed.)

`cd /d` will change the directory for you.

`&&` executes the second half after the `cd` goes through.

```
Dim obj As Object
Dim PythonExe As String
Dim Script As String

Set obj = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Program Files (x86)"""

Script = "C:\Users\User\Documents\testesbulkpdf\firsttry.py"

obj.Run "cmd /k cd /d" & PythonExe & "&& " & "python" & " " & Script
```

Comment: That's much better, now at least i can see what is going on my cmd. Thanks! We're close, i gues..

My cmd is informing a "PermissionError: [Errno 13]" Permission denied: 'try.pdf'

Any idea on why? I've not problems with this directory and this pc only have admin account.
Maybe something wrong with path?

[link to image of cmd](https://imgur.com/a/JmZdJeK)

Comment: Not sure, it looks like its the python that is throwing that error. You could try running the cmd as administrator though I'm not sure that would help here. or add a print statement in python to see where it is trying to write to.